# How to select just one first or last record compliant to a where clause with ScalaQuery?

Tags: scala, scalaquery

Having the following query template to select all:

```
val q = for {
  a <- Parameters[Int]
  b <- Parameters[Int]
  t <- T if t.a == a && t.b == b
  _ <- Query.orderBy(t.c, t.d)
} yield t
```

I need to modify it to select the very first (with minimum `c` and `d` minimum for this `c`) or the very last (with maximum `c` and `d` maximum for this `c`) record of those matching the `where` condition. I'd usually strongly prefer no other (than the last/first) records to be selected as there are hundreds thousands of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a potential danger here in how the OP's query is currently constructed. Run as is, getting the first or last result of a 100K result set is not terribly efficient (unlikely, yes, but the point is, the query places no limit on number of number of rows returned)

With straight SQL you would never do such a thing; instead you would tack on a `LIMIT 1`

In ScalaQuery, LIMIT = take(n), so add `take(1)` to get *a single record returned from the query itself*

```
val q = (for {
  a <- Parameters[Int]
  b <- Parameters[Int]
  t <- T if t.a == a && t.b == b
  _ <- Query.orderBy(t.c, t.d)
} yield t) take(1)
q.firstOption
```

Comment: Eh... ScalaQuery could *definitely* use some good round-up of all those fancy methods. (I failed to find one)

Comment: SQ documentation leaves a lot to be desired, I agree. Hopefully with the morph into SLICK coming early summer, there will be better docs (since SLICK is under TypeSafe umbrella, I'm expecting just that)

Comment: This doesn't compile, says "value take is not a member of org.scalaquery.ql.basic.BasicQueryTemplate[...]". Curiously, if replace the space before `take(1)` with a dot, my IDE (Idea) stops painting `take` in red, but the compiler still doesn't do...

Comment: @Ivan try "q.take(1).firstOption" I built against ScalaQuery 0.10 master, maybe there's a difference between that and 0.9x branch. Should not matter though, do you have the (for {...}) wrapped in parens?

Comment: "q.take(1).firstOption" produces `'}' expected but eof found.` error. I am building against 0.10.0-M1. Yes, I have the parens. Maybe the problem is caused by the fact I try to encapsulate my queries in the table model object (using `this` instead of `T` in the example) (but this works just for simple selects), I'll try to move them out... Another significant difference between reality and the example is that I use `Projection(a, b) <- Parameters[Int, Int]` for the parameters (I've came to this after writing the question as I could see no way to actually pass the parameters values otherwise).

Comment: Curious thing is that I can't use `a ~ b` instead of `Projection(a, b)`. In both cases my IDE highlights it (`~` or `Projection` as an error) but the compiler is ok with `Projection`.

Comment: well, start with the simplest approach and then work in the extras. Not sure about "this", I have db tables mapped to case class companion objects, and use the object in place of your T in the example. It's truly "flying by the seat of your pants" right now in SQ, we're on our own until Stefan Zeiger comes up for air with much anticipated SLICK release (he's giving a talk at Scala Days London tomorrow, stuck in France ;-( ...)

Comment: @Ivan you should look at this thread if you have not already done so; the multiple Parameters[Int] bit may be causing some issues "http://szeiger.de/blog/2009/08/06/efficient-parameterized-queries-in-scala-query/"

Comment: That's the post where I've taken the Projection way from.

Comment: By the way, I've just tried your solution (adding `take`) with a simple parameter-less query - seems ok. But unfortunately that's of little use as in real life I need 6 parameters, 4 of them representing a composite primary key. Thank you anyway, I would hardly find the direction to dig without your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

There is method `firstOption` defined on the Invoker trait, and by some magic it is available on the Query class. So maybe you can try it like this:

```
val q = for {
  a <- Parameters[Int]
  b <- Parameters[Int]
  t <- T if t.a == a && t.b == b
  _ <- Query.orderBy(t.c, t.d)
} yield t
q.firstOption
```